# Corona SDK and Lua Socket blocks animation

Tags: lua, coronasdk, luasocket

Here is my network handler:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/22fc110ad126ef3a2c5f

The problem is that when data is received it blocks my animiation (I have a wheel spinning when data has been requested) so it looks like the app have crashed and then after 1 second or 2, when the data has been received, it works like a charm.

This line seems to make sure that when waiting for an answer the app doesn't freeze:

```
local input,output = socket.select( { self.sock }, nil, 0 ) -- this is a way not to block runtime while reading socket. zero timeout does the trick
```

Here is another timeout setting:

```
 self.sock:settimeout(0)
```

I have tried to change them to 0.01 and 0.001 but with no luck. I'm not really sure how to make it so the animation doesn't freeze.

Maybe I should change to one of Coronas built in async network handler (with callback functions) or is it possible to modify this network handler so that the animation doesn't freeze?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Corona's network.* api, it's async so you won't have any blocking calls.

Documentation link: http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/network/index.html